# Adobe Reader XI search fail when pdf fileIdentifier (/ID) is set

Tags: php, search, pdf, adobe-reader

I am part of the R&OS pdf class for php developer team and noticed some strange behavior in Adobe Reader XI (11.0.5)

When a pdf file includes the fileIdentifier (/ID entry in trailer part) Adobe Reader failed to search for the text content.

Once I remove the /ID entry search is fully functioning.

Foxit Reader and Chrome reader search worked in both cases

Does anybody know why Adobe Reader (AAR) is behaving like this?

In addition I added both pdf files on pastebin.com. 
So you can download and test from there. Simple store it with the extension ".pdf"

http://pastebin.com/an5NaZcv - search failed

http://pastebin.com/ZyFZNQ36 - search ok

BINARY FILE WHICH IS NOT WORKING: *bug is fixed*

I reported this as bug in my application here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pdf-php/bugs/71/

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I can search both files for e.g. the word "gray" successfully using Adobe Reader 11.0.5; on the other hand providing the files via pastebin, a service intended for textual data, might have destroyed some important aspect. I would advice using some file server for binary files.

Comment: The question is so specific, that I think that only Adobe can answer it, I agree with @mkl, pasting binary in Pastebin might mess everything

Comment: Do you have `Fast Find` enabled in *Preferences*?

Comment: NOTE: these pdf files do not contain any binary stuff. So it should safe to copy & paste. Anyway I am going to upload the binaries... thankk
@mkl which OS are you using? Maybe its because I am using windows 8.1?!

Comment: I tested on Windows 7 in office.  @VadimR's idea should also be checked.

Comment: *these pdf files do not contain any binary stuff.* - a common misconception. Pdf files are binary files even if they look like plain text.

Comment: Well, it actually once bit me... Disable Fast Find, purge search cache, restart Acrobat. Useful option for people, nasty trap for developers.

Comment: I'm now at a Win8.1 Computer and I could search all the files both with Adobe Reader 11.0.4 and 11.0.5, and I could find 'gray' each time. Have you probably re-used an ID used in another document on your Computer before? Maybe a Prior Version of the same PDF? BTW, the file made available for binary download did not make Adobe Reader want to repair while it wanted to repair the textual ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty much sure I solved it by **clearing the fast search cache in Adobe Reader.**

**My explanation why this problem occurs:**

Even without encryption, the *fast find feature* from Adobe Reader is using the /ID entry (if it is set) to somehow identify all text content of the document.

Once I have cleared the *fast find cache* from "Preferences -> Search" I was again able to search

So in future I will use something similar to md5(#timestamp#) to make sure every document has its own unique fileIdentifer stored in /ID entry of the document trailer.

Thank you for your hints

Regards,
Ole

Comment: *So in future I will use something similar to md5(#timestamp#) to make sure every document has its own unique fileIdentifer stored in /ID entry of the document trailer.* - I would propose following a routine as presented in the PDF specification. And an ID is an ID is an ID.

Comment: I fully agree, but I also think noone knew that this effects the fast find feature in AAR. Anyway problem is solved.

Comment: It was new to me, too, but @VadimR seems to have had experienced something like that before. ;-)